# Cassandra path for range query with CL=2

Tags: cassandra-2.0, distributed-system, eventual-consistency

I'm modelling a toy email application in Cassandra. Say I'm storing emails in the `emails` table:

```
create table emails (
  recipient_uid int, 
  timestamp timestamp,
  content text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (recipient_uid, timestamp) );
```

Let's say we run Cassandra on a cluster of three nodes, **N1**, **N2**, and **N3**, `'replication_factor': 3`, and the quorum config `W=2`, `R=2`.

Given that `W=2`, under concurrent operations it is possible that nodes diverge and they store different sets of emails. For instance, we could have the following rows on all nodes:

```
recipient_uid | timestamp                | content
---------------+--------------------------+-------
             1 | 2010-02-09 23:49:07+0000 |     c1
             1 | 2010-02-04 22:11:16+0000 |     c2
```

And then an INSERT occurs which propagates only at nodes **N2** and **N3**; these two will have the following rows then:

```
recipient_uid | timestamp                | content
---------------+--------------------------+-------
             1 | 2010-02-09 23:49:07+0000 |     c1
             1 | 2010-02-04 22:11:16+0000 |     c2
             1 | 2010-12-13 05:52:46+0000 |     c3
```

Note that email with content `c3` is not replicated at **N1**, yet. Then a client does a SELECT (`R=2`) at **N1**:

```
select * from emails where recipient_uid = 1;
```

When this happens, node **N1** coordinates with the closest other node, say **N2**, and return all the three rows. (Assuming no speculative executor.)

**Question:**

What are the internals of this coordination step between **N1** and **N2**? Is there any documentation or can somebody point me to the relevant code chunk?

According to my current understanding, the relevant classes should be roughly:

- [ReadCallback.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/ReadCallback.java), and
- [AbstractReadExecutor.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/AbstractReadExecutor.java).

But I'm relying mainly on information from [ArchitectureInternals](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureInternals) which is incomplete and *specific for single-row requests*.

To be more precise: my main concern is if the coordinator **N1** is able to selectively pull just the missing row (in this case, the third row) from **N2**, then merge this row with the first two rows (which he has already) and finally reply to the client. What digests and/or data does **N1** exchange with **N2** to achieve this, if this is the case indeed?

EDIT: This doc on [Read Path](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadPathForUsers) also seems relevant, but it also assumes *single-row requests*, which I expect to be simpler than range queries.

EDIT2: [@ArielWeisberg](https://twitter.com/ArielWeisberg/status/697806382309863424) kindly shared this information:

Range queries are described by [PartitionRangeReadCommand](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b63e6eef53053099cf238179b71553916877923d/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/PartitionRangeReadCommand.java).

StorageProxy has [RangeIterator](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b63e6eef53053099cf238179b71553916877923d/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/StorageProxy.java#L1880) which uses [StorageProxy.getRestrictedRanges()](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b63e6eef53053099cf238179b71553916877923d/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/StorageProxy.java#L2252) to calculate a covering set of endpoints and ranges.

[StorageProxy.RangeCommandIterator](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b63e6eef53053099cf238179b71553916877923d/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/StorageProxy.java#L2010) is what materializes the results.